# Alternative dns not working on windows 10 Home

Tags: windows, networking

I have a local dns for my intranet which is 192.168.2.2, I use it to Manage local domains within the intranet:

```
http: //test.vh// pointing to -> 192.168.2.22
http: /dev.vh// pointing to -> 192.168.2.23
```

Today I decided to verify if I could improve the speed and quality of the internet by configuring a secondary and alternative DNS.

when doing the verifications the best option is to use OPENDNS:

*Part 1: it does not improve quality.*

```
DNS1: 192.168.2.2
DNS2: 208.67.222.220
DNS3: 208.67.229.222
```

*Part 2: quality improves but I lose access to local domains..*

```
DNS1: 208.67.222.220
DNS2: 192.168.2.2
DNS3: 208.67.229.222
```

*Part 3: quality improves but I lose access to local domains..*

```
DNS1: 208.67.222.220
DNS2: 208.67.229.222
DNS3: 192.168.2.2
```

**Why Windows 10 Home does not use secondary and tertiary DNS to search for domains in the internal network, I understand that it only happens if there is a fall back of the primary DNS, but the use of the other dns can be forced if there is no access to a Web page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only real solution to this, is to run multiple internal DNS servers (if you really feel you need the redundancy), as your primary and secondary, and to use forwarders configured from your DNS servers up to the public resolvers you want to use. You probably don't need multiple internal servers for DNS, unless uptime is critical to you.

That way your servers will always get first stab at resolving your local domain, and will only pass upstream if your local server doesn't host the zone you are trying to resolve.

Also Windows will not check more than one DNS server per resolution. Secondary servers are only used when the first is unresponsive, not when it can't find a domain. So it wont just try the next server because the first didn't carry the zone.

So have your clients point to your DNS, and have your DNS forward unresolved queries up to the OpenDNS servers.

Additionally, you can set the secondary DNS on your clients to point to OpenDNS in case your internal server goes down and you want to limit the impact of that failure. you would lose local domain resolution, but your clients wouldn't experience a full lost of connectivity to the web.

also consider putting PiHole inline between your clients and your dns server, if you want to add ad/malware-blocking.

Final note, I like the DNS Benchmarking utility from Gibson Research for finding the fastest DNS servers from my particular location. I usually find several that are faster than OpenVPN: https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm

Comment: The part about multiple servers is really unnecessary - OP only introduced multiple servers because in their mind secondary DNS was the solution to their problems. Otherwise, a good answer.

Comment: clarified that that is not really necessary unless site-specific requirements indicate the need for multiple servers.

Answer (score 2):

The tl;dr answer:

Secondary DNS is used when primary DNS fails. Empty response is not a failure, therefore Windows trusts it and doesn't query the second server.

The solution to your problem is to make your primary server forward queries that it can't respond to to another DNS server, for example OpenDNS.

Answer (score 1):

DNS doesn't know, nor does it care if you're attempting to view a webpage.  DNS simply takes the name you've provided and looks up the IP Number for that name. If DNS lookup cannot connect to the Primary DNS Server, then and only then will DNS attempt the lookup on the Secondary DNS Server. If you are looking up a name that doesn't exist in the Primary Server, since it is up, it will return that the DNS record does not exist. In addition, DNS lookups are cached according to the SOA record of the domain you are looking up.

Changing the order servers are queried will not impact the "speed and quality" of the internet unless your primary server is unreachable and the DNS lookup must query the secondary server (we are talking the difference of milliseconds).